# How to press on listview to show infomation // Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

now i try to query data from database [SQLite] to show by search
which next i want to press on listview that found after search but that error

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
>                                                                                     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
>                                                                                     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>                                                                                     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>                                                                                     at th.kusrc.devbeginner.sqlite4.SearchActivity$1.onItemClick(SearchActivity.java:50)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

In SearchActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    Search_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_name);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    // OnClick Item
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {

            String user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_NAME"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Selected User : " + user_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchContact);
    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void searchContact() {
    search_name = Search_name.getText().toString();
    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDbHelper.getContact(search_name, sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name, mobile, email;
            name = cursor.getString(0);
            mobile = cursor.getString(1);
            email = cursor.getString(2);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name, mobile, email);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

in userDbHelper

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USERINFO.DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
        "CREATE TABLE " + UserContact.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT," +
                UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_MOB + " TEXT," + UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ");";

public UserDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("Database Operation", "Database created......");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database Operation", "Table created......");
}
public Cursor getContact(String user_name, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String[] projections = {UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_MOB, UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
    String selection = UserContact.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selection_args = {user_name};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(UserContact.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

and UserContact.NewUserInfo

```
    public class UserContact {

public static abstract class NewUserInfo {
    public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String USER_MOB = "user_mob";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_info";
}
```

}

[image: after search if press on listview that's error]

How can I fix it?

EDIT : Update userDbHelper

Comment: How can create new database statement?
please give me a CREATE statement

Comment: ok, i updated userDbHelper.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_NAME"));
```

You are using column name as "USER_NAME" whereas you have defined it as

```
      public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
```

So correct the case used for column name.

Comment: it's mean i will fix to 
String user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_name")); right ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing all your entire code, but it is obvious the line that causes the crash is:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_NAME"));
```

I assume `cursor` is a member of your `SearchActivity`. I do not know why you think it will necessarily point to the correct row (as I see you update it in other places and it is used to iterate over the whole DB). I think you have 2 options:

1) When you create the list item, you save the user name in a holder view (see this [example](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)). Thus you can access the data on the click listener directly without quarrying the DB.

2) Update your click listener and fetch the correct row from the DB per the location. Something like:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {
        // You need to write initTheCursorToPointIndex() on your own (I am not sure how you organized your data so I can't implement it)
        cursor = initTheCursorToPointIndex(position); 
        String user_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_NAME"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Selected User : " + user_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```